# Matplotlib Toolbar is not displaying icons in PySimpleGUI or Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, uinavigationbar, pysimplegui

I have followed tutorials from PySimpleGUI and from Matplotlib in order to embed the default navigation bar in the GUI. All the buttons are functional but they do not have icons they have the names of the buttons with the letters overlapping (as seen below). What am i missing?

[Image of the navigation bar i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rSKM.png)

This is the code i was using:
I did try installing the dependencies on the matplotlib website and cannot find anyone else who has had this problem

Edit: I’m using a Mac. I have these versions installed.

Python 3.9.12

MatPlotLib 3.7.1

PySimpleGUI 4.60.4

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np

"""
    Embedding the Matplotlib toolbar into your application

"""

# ------------------------------- This is to include a matplotlib figure in a Tkinter canvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk


def draw_figure_w_toolbar(canvas, fig, canvas_toolbar):
    if canvas.children:
        for child in canvas.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    if canvas_toolbar.children:
        for child in canvas_toolbar.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)


class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# ------------------------------- PySimpleGUI CODE

layout = [
    [sg.T('Graph: y=sin(x)')],
    [sg.B('Plot'), sg.B('Exit')],
    [sg.T('Controls:')],
    [sg.Canvas(key='controls_cv')],
    [sg.T('Figure:')],
    [sg.Column(
        layout=[
            [sg.Canvas(key='fig_cv',
                       # it's important that you set this size
                       size=(400 * 2, 400)
                       )]
        ],
        background_color='#DAE0E6',
        pad=(0, 0)
    )],
    [sg.B('Alive?')]

]

window = sg.Window('Graph with controls', layout)
if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):  # always,  always give a way out!
        break
    elif event is 'Plot':
        # ------------------------------- PASTE YOUR MATPLOTLIB CODE HERE
        plt.figure(1)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        DPI = fig.get_dpi()
        # ------------------------------- you have to play with this size to reduce the movement error when the mouse hovers over the figure, it's close to canvas size
        fig.set_size_inches(404 * 2 / float(DPI), 404 / float(DPI))
        # -------------------------------
        x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
        y = np.sin(x)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.title('y=sin(x)')
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        plt.grid()

        # ------------------------------- Instead of plt.show()
        draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['fig_cv'].TKCanvas, fig, window['controls_cv'].TKCanvas)

window.close()
```

Comment: It maybe something related your working environment, it work fine on my WIN10. Check if it is OK if there's only the code for matplotlib lib. It will be better if you can provide more information about your environment to help people to find the root cause and solution.

Comment: I’m working on MacOS. Matplotlib figures display properly in their own window. It is only when I embed the code that the icons do not appear.

Comment: Just found another post about a poster using Tkinker, apparently, its a display fault with all MacOS, it would be great if anyone has a fix but it appears to be one of those things.